# hql and @EmbeddedId

Tags: jpa

Is it possible to query on Embeddable object from query? Here are my Entities:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "A")
 public class UnitParam implements Serializable {
    ...
    @EmbeddedId
    private UnitParamId unitParamId;
    ....
 }

 @Embeddable
 public class UnitParamId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PcID", nullable = false)
    private short pcId;

    @Column(name = "UnitID", nullable = false)
    private short unitId;

    @Column(name = "ParamID", nullable = false)
    private int paramId;
    ...
 }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "B")
 public class ParameterMapping extends BasicEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PcID", referencedColumnName = "PcID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "UnitID", referencedColumnName = "UnitID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ParamID", referencedColumnName = "ParamID") })
    private UnitParam unitParam;
 ...
 }
```

Here is the query that fails:

```
  select p.id, p.name as name, 
   p.unitParam.unitParamId.pcId as processCell,
   p.unitParam.unitParamId.unitId as unit,
   p.unitParam.unitParamId.paramId as paramId 
   from ParameterMapping p
```

With the Exception:Caused by:  **org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: unitParamId of: ParameterMapping 
[SELECT p.id, p.name as name, p.unitParam.unitParamId.pcId as processCell, p.unitParam.unitParamId.unitParam.unitId as unit,
p.unitParam.unitParamId.paramId as paramId FROM de.koehl.mes.model.ParameterMapping p]**

Thank you in advance.


I found the problem: First Problem was mixing field/property access. After fixing that, the ManyToOne generates the columns, but no foreign key! But I don't know why!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `unitParam` field in `UnitParamId`, so the path `p.unitParam.unitParamId.unitParam.unitId` is invalid. Change your query to

```
select p.id, p.name as name, 
       p.unitParam.unitParamId.pcId as processCell,
       p.unitParam.unitParamId.unitId as unit,
       p.unitParam.unitParamId.paramId as paramId 
from ParameterMapping p
```

or even better:

```
select p.id, p.name as name, 
       unitParam.unitParamId.pcId as processCell,
       unitParam.unitParamId.unitId as unit,
       unitParam.unitParamId.paramId as paramId 
from ParameterMapping p
inner join p.unitParam unitParam
```

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo: p.unitParam.unitParamId.unitParam.unitId. My Query looks like your first suggestion and it does not work.

Comment: I found that the ManyToOne creates an varbinary column and not three columns: PcId, UnitId, and ParamId. So, the query cant't work! Oh see mixed field/property access.